# Weird path behavior when using os.path and pathlib Mac OSX Catalina

Tags: python-3.x, python-os, pathlib

I have an image called `image1.png` its real path on my macbook is :

> /Users/emadboctor/Desktop/images/image1.png

and the image is found by calling:

> `images = os.listdir('/Users/emadboctor/Desktop/images/image1.png')`

let's say I want to get the same path above by calling

> `os.path.abspath(images[0])`

or

> `pathlib.Path(images[0]).absolute()`

and the current working directory is:

> `/Users/emadboctor/Desktop/another`

Expected path: `/Users/emadboctor/Desktop/images/image1.png`

What I actually get: `/Users/emadboctor/Desktop/another/image1.png`

To reproduce the problem here are the sequence of steps:

```
>>> import os
>>> os.getcwd()
'/Users/emadboctor/Desktop/another'
>>> os.path.abspath('../images/image1.png')
'/Users/emadboctor/Desktop/images/image1.png'  # This is the correct/expected path
>>> os.listdir('../images')
['image1.png']
>>> images = [os.path.abspath(image) for image in os.listdir('../images')]
>>> images
['/Users/emadboctor/Desktop/another/image1.png']  # This is the unexpected/incorrect path
>>> import pathlib
>>> pathlib.Path('../images/image1.png').parent.absolute()
PosixPath('/Users/emadboctor/Desktop/another/../images')  # This is also the unexpected/incorrect path
```

How to get the path I'm expecting without hardcoding the correct prefix?

```
[f'/Users/emadboctor/Desktop/images/{image}' for image os.listdir('../images')]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the function `resolve`.

```py
>>> from pathlib import Path
>>>
>>> Path.cwd()
WindowsPath('d:/Docs/Notes/Notes')
>>> p = Path('../../test/lab.svg')
>>> p
WindowsPath('../../test/lab.svg')
>>> p.absolute()
WindowsPath('d:/Docs/Notes/Notes/../../test/lab.svg')
>>> p.absolute().resolve()
WindowsPath('D:/Docs/test/lab.svg')
```

Comment: Okay, my bad I should've converted it to a string, it works.